# There are no "infinitesimally small" intervals in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, real-numbers

this question is concerning a previous question I asked, [In more detail, why does L'Hospital's not apply here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2317754/in-more-detail-why-does-lhospitals-not-apply-here). @md2perpe's response spiked my curiosity. They said "...there are no infinitesimally small interval in $\mathbb{R}$".

I initially accepted this by thinking about an interval around $0$ and considering $10^{-3}$ as something somewhat close to $0$. Something even closer to $0$, however, is $10^{-256}$. Obviously, you could continue this indefinitely by choosing smaller and smaller numbers, of which there are infinitely many.

I then thought about this in a more physical sense, if I had a point labelled "$0$" and tried to get infinitesimally close to it on either side, would this not be considered an infinitesimally small interval?

Could someone please clarify my confusion.

I hope I am not abusing the concept of the infinitesimal, I have much to learn :)

Comment: "tried to get infinitesimally close to it"  What would this mean?

Comment: I honestly don't know. Is it inappropriate to think this way?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ contains only numbers. It doesn't contain a number that is infinitely close to $0$ but distinct from it, even though it is correct that you can get aribitrarily close to $0$ without being $0$ itself. The reason the naive concept of infinitesimals is problematic is that there is always, for every number $0 \neq a  \in \mathbb{R}$ which isn't $0$ itself, another number that is closer to $0$ than $a$. This would not be true for a thing such as an infinitesimal, so speaking of that concept within $\mathbb{R}$ is generally something one has to be very careful with.

Comment: As an aside, in nonstandard analysis, where you do have infinitesimal intervals, a function being differentiable at $0$ does not imply there exists an infinitesimally small interval on which the function is differentiable! You can only conclude such a thing in the case where there exists an $\epsilon$ that is *not* infinitesimally small for which $f$ is differentiable on $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, but if such a thing existed you wouldn't need to appeal to infinitesimals in the first place.

Comment: Yes Hurkyl, that was cleared up in my linked question about L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: You could continue this indefinitely by choosing smaller and smaller numbers but the problem is that as long as you continue doing so you keep changing the interval if you were to stop after any number of steps you would get a finite small number. You can apply the same logic with approaching $0$ you keep taking points closer and closer to $0$ but to get an interval you must stop to take a point and between two points there is always another point.

Comment: In the physics sense, there is a unit of length so small, you can't be half this unit away from something.  In that sense...

Comment: On the mathematical side, getting **arbitrarily close** to infinitely small is not the same as **being** infinitely small...

Comment: It is possible to define a non-empty open interval so small that no rational number is provably contained in it:

$(0, 10^{-\text{BB}(10^4)})$

where $\text{BB}(10^4)$ is the $10000^{\text{th}}$ [busy beaver number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver).  That's because a Turing machine with fewer than $10^4$ states can be [designed to find a contradiction in ZFC if one exists](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg23030734-300-turing-machine-should-run-forever-unless-maths-itself-is-wrong/).

Comment: @DanBrumleve But $10^{-2\text{BB}(10^4)}$ is provably contained in that interval. We don't know how small that number is, but that's irrelevant.